# How to Duplicate Input Subdirectory Structure for Batch File Output?

Tags: batch-file

I want to use this one-line script to run an awk script on all the *.xmp files in one directory and place the processed files in a second directory with the same subdirectory structure.

The batch file FixXMP.bat looks like this:

```
 forfiles -p "%1" -s -m *.xmp /c "cmd /c gawk -f fixxmp.awk < @file > %2\@file"
```

I run the script like this:

```
 FixXMP indir outdir
```

where indir is the directory that contains the input files in subdirectories and outdir is the where the subdirectories will be duplicated and the output files stored.

This works fine except that all the output files go in the output directory without duplicating the input subdirectory structure.

I have no idea how to accomplish this.  Can anyone help me change this script to duplicate the input subdirectory structure for the output?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Look at `xcopy /?` especially options `/T` and `/E`

Comment: LotPings, I'm not sure how xcopy helps.  If I wanted to copy the files into a duplicate the folder structure the /E option would do it, and if I wanted to create an empty folder structure /T would do it, but I need to direct the awk command output to the correct folder in the output folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

- Once forfiles recurses into subfolders the static `%2` destination doesn't match anymore.
- Also you need to use `<@path` for the input file

I see two possible solutions:

1. Using `forfiles` with the `@RelPath` option
2. using a `for /f` parsing the output of a `dir /B/S "%1\*.xmp"` and
   then exchanging `indir` with `outdir` in the found
   drive:\path\filename.ext.

If you first duplicate the directory structure with `xcopy /S/T/E "%InDir%" "%OutDir%\"` you don't need to check if each single destination directory already exists (as already pointed out in my comment).

Provided `fixXMP.awk` is in the same folder as `fixXMP.bat` :

```
:: FixXMP.bat
@Echo off
xcopy /S/T/E "%~1" "%~2\"
forfiles -p "%~1" -s -m *.xmp /c "cmd /c gawk -f %~dp0\fixXMP.awk <@path >%~2\@relpath"
```

Sample output on my ramdrive A: before running the batch:

```
> tree A:\ /F
A:\
├───InDir
│   └───Sub1
│       └───Sub2
│               Test.xmp
│
└───OutDir
```

and after :

```
> tree A:\ /F
A:\
├───InDir
│   └───Sub1
│       └───Sub2
│               Test.xmp
│
└───OutDir
    └───Sub1
        └───Sub2
                Test.xmp
```

Batch variant with `for /f` and same result:

```
:: FixXMP.bat
@Echo off & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
xcopy /S/T/E "%~1" "%~2\"
For /f "delims=" %%A in ('Dir /B/S "%1\*.xmp" ') Do (
    Set "InFile=%%~fA"
    Set "OutFile=!InFile:%~1=%~2!"
    gawk -f "%~dp0\fixXMP.awk" <"%%A" >"!OutFile!"
)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide a detailed and well thought out solution.  This works perfectly as long as I have no spaces in my paths.  However I do have spaces in my paths.  I thought this was just a matter of adding quoted quote characters, but when I try that it doesn't work.  Specifically I did this:
forfiles -p "%~1" -s -m *.xmp /c "cmd /c %~dp0gawk -f %~dp0fixxmp.awk < ^"@path^" > ^"%~2\@relpath^""
but that gives the message "The system cannot find the file specified."  Can you tell me how to fix this?  
Thanks,
Mike